# Passing Django variable to an accordion attribute in HTML

Tags: html, django, accordion

I am newbie to Django and apologize in advance for such a basic question to most of you, but I looked for similar questions all over and haven't encountered a workable solution.

I am trying to create a Bootstrap Accordion for each item of a Django for-loop.
So a list of items is displayed, and when you click on one item, the description of it will collapse to show.
The segment currently looks like this using [this template](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/components/accordion/):

```
<head>
   <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-MrcW6ZMFYlzcLA8Nl+NtUVF0sA7MsXsP1UyJoMp4YLEuNSfAP+JcXn/tWtIaxVXM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>


<body>
    {% for item in items %}
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="headingOne">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-bs-target="#collapseOne" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseOne">
                    {{ item }}
                </button>
            </h2>

            <div id="collapseOne" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="headingOne" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    {{ item.description }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Now, this is giving the same value (`collapseOne`) to `data-bs-toggle`, `aria-controls` and `id` of `accordion-collapse`class(collapsing element) for every for-loop item, resulting in all the accordion items collapsing when one of them is clicked though I want only the clicked one to collapse.

So I tried to pass the Django variable as such:

1. `{{ item }}` in place of `collapseOne`
2. `{{ forloop.counter }}` in place of `collapseOne`

The accordion still shows, but it doesn't collapse when clicked.

Is there a way to pass a Django variable to attributes of accordion-item? Or any other work around?

I'd appreciate your advice.

Comment: A great way I personally make sure dynamic things work is to first only focus on the HTML/CSS/Javascript part with generic example names/values. When the layout is working, I start to replace everything with Django-variables. In case of a list, I would start with just the for-loop that creates the repeating elements, than integrate data from the specific iteration. That way I am always sure if something breaks, in which part it is

Comment: Thank you for your advice! Yes I knew both the accordion layout and the list of the loop items worked independently, but I couldn't integrate the list into the accordion the way I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to use the `{{ forloop.counter }}` - just make sure to update the value everywhere you need:

```
{% for item in items %}
    <div class="accordion" id="accordionExample">
        <div class="accordion-item">
            <h2 class="accordion-header" id="heading-{{ forloop.counter }}">
                <button class="accordion-button" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-bs-target="#collapse-{{ forloop.counter }}" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapse-{{ forloop.counter }}">
                    {{ item }}
                </button>
            </h2>

            <div id="collapse-{{ forloop.counter }}" class="accordion-collapse collapse" aria-labelledby="heading-{{ forloop.counter }}" data-bs-parent="#accordionExample">
                <div class="accordion-body">
                    {{ item.description }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Thank you! All I needed was put "heading-" and "collapse-" before the Django variable.